# form submit from onclick function

Tags: javascript, form-submit

I have a function called formFill() and I want it to submit the form after it is done. Right now the function is ran by an onclick within a div like this:

```
<div class="stormData" onClick="formFill('11-04-14','11-04-14','TX','none');">11-04-14 - TX</div>
```

this works fine but I wanted the function to submit the form also so I added document.theform.submit(); to the function and it does not work. Here is my function.

```
function formFill(a, b, c, d){
        theform.from.value = a;
        theform.to.value = b;
        if(d != "none"){
            theform.kmlFile.value = d;
            theform.hailswath.checked = true;
            document.getElementById("kmlLabel").innerHTML = d;
        }
        for(var i = 0;i < document.getElementById("stateSelect").length;i++){
            if(document.getElementById("stateSelect").options[i].value == c ){
                document.getElementById("stateSelect").selectedIndex = i;
            }
        }
        document.theform.submit();
    }
```

Comment: Which browser? And do you get a JavaScript error, and does your page render in quirks mode or standard mode (what's the DOCTYPE)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a form element with name='submit'?  If so rename it and your function will work.

Answer (score 1):

after you finish doing whatever preprocessing you want to do, you can do:

```
myForm.submit()
```

edit: make sure you are calling .submit() on the right object; is your `theform` object a global variable that is pointing to the correct form element? e.g. you can do document.getElementById('id_of_your_form').submit(); if that works and `theform.submit()` does not work, you probably want to make sure that your earlier calls to theform.from were working properly